# How to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word when Windows Authentication is Enabled?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, iis-7.5

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word for opening the word document from C# in ASP.NET Web Application and replacing some of the bookmarks programmatically. I use windows authentication for auto login. It works just fine when running from visual studio. But, after publishing it, I get Access denied error while application try to open the word document. Here is the error which I get.

**Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))**

I tried all the solutions posted over internet like (Changing the permissions for word in DCOMCNFG, Granting Read/Write full control for the folder,etc. Is there any other solution since I use windows authentication ? Or Where I am I going wrong ?Please Help.

Thanks  in Advance

Comment: Do not use the Office Interop libraries in ASP.NET. You will get all sorts of hard to diagnose weird errors, it will be slow, and your copy of Office is likely not licensed to run on a server. Microsoft [says don't do it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office). Instead, use a native .NET library such as [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) or [DocX](https://github.com/WordDocX/DocX).

Comment: Can we find and replace words in document footer if we use DocX ? Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The possible workaround is modify your project's platform from 'Any CPU' to 'X86' (in Project's Properties, Build/Platform's Target)

Mostly the root cause of this issue is because VSS Interop is a managed assembly using 32-bit Framework and the dll contains a 32-bit COM object. If you run this COM dll in 64 bit environment, you will get the error message.

Source :- https://forums.asp.net/t/1119052.aspx?Retrieving+COM+class+factory+failed+due+to+the+following+error+80040154

Comment: Your OS is 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: My OS is 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to fix my issue. Its basically a permission issue.
Since my operating system was 64bit, microsoft.office.interop.word needs all permissions for 32bit. It doesn't work for 64bit.
Procedure which helped me was:

1. Workaround

Go to Start -> Run.
Type DCOMCNFG. (This will load the "Component Services")
Go to Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> DCOM Config ->
Word-> security tab -> give access

If MSWord not found in DCOM Config then
In Run window: type MMC -32

File -> add/Remove snap in

-> Add  component services

->Computers

->My Computer

->DCOM Config

->Microsoft Word Application

Give access local services, Administrator, IUSRS, IIS Worker Process, IIS AppPool/DefaultAppPool

2. Workaround

open registry editor (regedit)
Search for winword.exe, copy the AppId/Guid for word from “HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID\WINWORD.EXE”

Open Component Services (dcomcnfg), Go to Computers->MyComputer->DCOM Cnfg

Select the application with the guid copied from registry.
Right click on it, select properties, select Identity tab, select “Interactive User”, click on “Apply” button.

Here is the link which helped me:
[Here is the link which helped me.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e3163fad-d87e-46ba-95e5-87ae9a421a73/word-interop-deployment-on-server-retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid?forum=worddev)

Thank You